# How to setup an asynchronous div in an asp.net MVC site.master page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for helping getting a div block in a site.master to become ajaxified. My site is using .net 3.5 and mvc 2. The site.master has these frameworks in it already...

MicrosoftAjax.js
MicrosoftMvcAjax.js
moo tools 1.2.5
jquery 1.4.2

The content of my div frame can come from a partial view or just rest inside the site master. The content is essentially a table of database records. Each row has a delete button. When the delete button is clicked, I want the table to refresh asynchronously from the rest of the page so that the record is no longer visible.

I am relatively new to MVC, but I've been doing web forms for years. I have tried to use "using (ajax...)" and straight up jquery, but I've had no success with either. I know it can be done, and I'd appreciate any help.